# All foreign keys are 'Null'

Tags: php, mysql, database

When inserting data into the table that works as it should. However when looking at the tables I noticed none of the foreign keys are working. Here is the 'Pizza' table which should be taking the foreign keys of `BaseID` and `ToppingID` from the other tables:

[image: Pizza Table]

As the picture shows above, the ToppingID is null. Whereas in the actual 'PizzaToppings' table as shown below, the ToppingID is **not** null:

[image: PizzaToppings Table]

This is currently happening to all my foreign keys throughout the database.

However this throws the error of:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails (`pizzadelivery`.`pizza`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_BaseID` FOREIGN KEY (`BaseID`) REFERENCES `pizzabase` (`BaseID`))

Comment: Where is your insert code?

Comment: What do you get as a result of SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%FORE%' and SHOW global VARIABLES LIKE '%FORE%'

Comment: Are you asking why that `CONSTRAINT` doesn't prevent the column from being `NULL`, or are you asking why your `INSERT` query doesn't populate the column?

Comment: And where is the definition of `PizzaBase`

Comment: @Script47 PHP insertion code: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/j9nx-hzbh

Comment: **Side Note:** @BenFoster your code is actually quite well written compared to other questions. Consider working on your question formatting too in the future.

Comment: @deceze I am relatively new to MySQL and PHP so I am trying to get an understanding of why the value is null in the Pizza table, I am assuming there is something wrong with the insert query that linked above.

Comment: Looking at your linked code (put the code into the question itself!): you're never putting anything into the `ToppingID` column.

Comment: @deceze My understanding was that the `ToppingID INT AUTO_INCREMENT` would auto increment the value by 1 for each topping added? Also my screenshot of my PizzaTopping table itself shows the value to be '1', so why is it null in the 'Pizza' table?

Comment: @BenFoster yes, it is an AI field in the table that it has been DEFINED in, not the referenced table. In the reference table you have to pass the ID of the topping too. Consider reading up on [table relationships](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-tutorial-excerpt/5.7/en/example-foreign-keys.html).

Comment: Inserting something into `PizzaToppings` does not automatically put anything into `Pizza`! The database would have no way of knowing what row in `Pizza` to put the `ToppingID` into.

Comment: So my mistake was assuming a foreign key would transfer the `ToppingID` over, when in fact it would require something like a join to do so?

Comment: Each query stands on its own, the database can't infer that you are making some logical connection between two independent queries and would like to cross-insert some ids. Yes, making that assumption was the problem. You need to first insert into `PizzaToppings`, and then insert into `Pizza` with the new id you just got from `PizzaToppings`.

Comment: @deceze Okay I tried what you suggested and attempted to insert the foreign key values into the Pizza table using this code: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/urdi-j2cb. However this throws the error of:  _Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pizzadelivery`.`pizza`, CONSTRAINT `FK_BaseID` FOREIGN KEY (`BaseID`) REFERENCES `pizzabase` (`BaseID`))_

Comment: Update your question, don't expect to get this solved in a comments thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $toppingID = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
> ```

`$toppingID` here is an array, probably ending up bound as the string `'Array'` in your final query, which obviously is a non-existent ID and violates your constraint (that's what constraints do, they ensure the datum is present in the other table).

You also don't want to use `MAX()` to get the id; it is not guaranteed that the new id has the highest number in the column, and it's not safe from race conditions if you're doing several queries in parallel. What you want is to get the *last insert id*:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO PizzaToppings ...');
...
$stmt->execute();
$toppingId = $pdo->lastInsertId();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO PizzaBase ...');
...
$stmt->execute();
$baseId = $pdo->lastInsertId();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO Pizza (..., ToppingID, BaseID) VALUES (..., :ToppingID, :BaseID)');
...
$stmt->bindParam(':ToppingID',$toppingId);
$stmt->bindParam(':BaseID',$baseId);
$stmt->execute();
```